# Get radio button value xcode 4 applescript

Tags: xcode, xcode4, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

All, 
I have a cocoa-applescript application that run a shell command (sets hostname according to user input) when a "install" push button is clicked:

```
on InstallButton_(sender)
    set hostName to ""
    set hostName to textField's stringValue as string
    do shell script ("/usr/sbin/scutil --set HostName " & hostName) with administrator privileges
    do shell script ("/usr/sbin/scutil --set ComputerName " & hostName) with administrator privileges
end InstallButton_
```

I would like to expand the program by adding 3 radio buttons. If any or all of these radio buttons (list) are selected when the "install" push button is pushed I would like to execute a command that correlates to each radio button. So if only the 1st 2 radio button are selected, execute only those 2 command.

How can I get the selected values of a matrix of radio buttons?

Comment: I wasnt able to find a solution using a radio button (list) but I was able to find out how to get the exact result using checkboxes.


        property checkBox : missing value
        set checkBoxValue to ""
        set checkBoxValue to checkBox's integerValue as string
        #display dialog checkBoxValue
        if checkBoxValue = 1
            #run policy
        end

if the checkbox is checked the checkBoxValue parameter = 1 if it is not checked the value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt able to find a solution using a radio button (list) but I was able to find out how to get the exact result using checkboxes.

```
property checkBox : missing value 
set checkBoxValue to "" 
set checkBoxValue to checkBox's integerValue as string 
#display dialog checkBoxValue 
if checkBoxValue = 1 
  #run policy 
end
```

if the checkbox is checked the checkBoxValue parameter = 1 if it is not checked the value is 0.